# HTML Dom images

Tags: html, css

I have a parallax page template. I have multiple sections. Each sections contain an image and text. I want images remain fixed at its position just like `background-attachment: fixed`. But I have images in HTML. I can't use these images as backgrounds.

Is there any solution for this so I can make parallax effect for DOM images?

http://jsfiddle.net/fn8p8qr5/embedded/result/

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with `<img />` too, can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Actually content and images will be changed. and it is updated from back end. Client needs that images in HTML so he can change and update any thing.

Comment: Then use background-images, but provide a means for him/her to update those background-images using JavaScript; which I presume you're using anyway, given that it appears to be interactive in some way?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fn8p8qr5/embedded/result/

Comment: David Thomas, I really appreciate your comment . I can do it with JavaScript  but I want HTML CSS solution just alternative of background-attachment:fixed for Images in DOM.

Comment: Is there a reason `position:fixed` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, in HTML you can set your image with `data-background` attribute which will be `background` and you can apply parallax effect to it. If you are using Wordpress or some other CMS you can insert code snippet in `data-background` and you can let your client change `background` for each section.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/341/)**

```js
$('section').each(function() {
  var background = $(this).data('background');
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+background+')');
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: table;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.section-content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section data-background="http://placehold.it/1920x860">
  <div class="section-content">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, facilis! Porro in pariatur aliquam, fugiat voluptatibus eaque optio accusantium reiciendis dolores quo fuga, placeat illo eius fugit rem quaerat enim.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section data-background="http://placehold.it/1920x860/3366ff/ffffff">
  <div class="section-content">  
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, facilis! Porro in pariatur aliquam, fugiat voluptatibus eaque optio accusantium reiciendis dolores quo fuga, placeat illo eius fugit rem quaerat enim.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section data-background="http://placehold.it/1920x860/99ff33/ffffff">
  <div class="section-content">  
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, facilis! Porro in pariatur aliquam, fugiat voluptatibus eaque optio accusantium reiciendis dolores quo fuga, placeat illo eius fugit rem quaerat enim.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Much appreciated Nenad Vracar . but this is not the required solution I also have other solutions with JavaScript and jquery  but I want the solution with CSS and HTML only.